# Binding an interface to a constructed concrete class in a Laravel5 service provider

Tags: php, laravel-5, service-provider

I have an interface that I would like to bind to a concrete class. The thing is, the concrete class requires some configuration items when instantiated. Here's what I did:

```
...

class FileMakerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('FileMakerInterface', function ($app){
            $username = env('FM_USERNAME');
            $password = env('FM_PASSWORD');
            $host     = env('FM_HOST');
            $database = env('FM_DATABASE');

            return new SSCSimpleFm(compact('username', 'password', 'host', 'database'));
        });
    }
}
```

I'm grabbing the config items I need and then passing in a newly constructed concrete class.

The problem is when I try injecting the interface into my dev controller to test it out:

```
...

use App\Services\FileMakerInterface;

class DevController extends Controller
{

    public function testFmConnect(FileMakerInterface $fm){
        return $fm;
    }
}
```

I get the error that the interface is not instantiable:

[image]

And I definitely included my service provider in `config/app.php`:

```
     /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    App\Providers\FileMakerServiceProvider::class
```

I know that  can bind the classes in my service provider like so:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('FileMakerInterface', 'SSCSimpleFm');
}
```

but if I do it that way, I can't inject the credentials.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re binding the concrete class to `FileMakerInterface` only. It needs a fully-qualified namespace:

```
$this->app->bind('App\Services\FileMakerInterface', function ($app) {
    return new SSCSimpleFm([
        'host'     => env('FM_HOST'),
        'username' => env('FM_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('FM_PASSWORD'),
        'database' => env('FM_DATABASE'),
    ]);
}
```

Now, when you type-hint `App\Services\FileMakerInterface`, you’ll get an instance of the bound class back instead.

Comment: So that worked as far as binding to my concrete class (thank you), but now I run into an error `UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 403:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.` This happens after the concrete object is constructed. Any quick ideas or should I submit a different stackoverflow question for it?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz Different issue so different question :)

Comment: [Already done ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862339/error-the-response-content-must-be-a-string-or-object-implementing-tostring) :)